# Ajax обновление textarea с запросом в БД

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Доброго времени суток. Не очень разбираюсь с php, поэтому вопрос сюда:
 У меня есть такой код, но он сохраняет данные в .json файл. А мне нужно переделать его так, чтобы он отсылал данные в табличку Mysql на сервере.
(Бд-шку я уже создал, в ней создал таблицу на 2 столбца: id и text непосредственно).

Что в итоге должно быть: Есть одно поле textarea, которое постоянно содержит введеный текст. (То есть при перезагрузке страницы, или входе с другого компьютера - мы должны видеть последний введеный текст). Некая заметка в своём роде.

```
<?php
$note_name = 'note.json';
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])){
    // Запрос AJAX
    if(isset($_POST['note'])){
        file_put_contents($note_name, $_POST['note']);
        echo '{"saved":1}';
    }
    exit;
    echo '{"saved":0}';
}
$note_content = '';
if( file_exists($note_name) ){
    $note_content = htmlspecialchars( file_get_contents($note_name) );
}
?>
```

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала вам необходимо подключиться к базе данных, для этого необходимо знать адрес БД, логин, пароль, имя БД.

Это упрощенный вариант, который показывает примерную логику работы, здесь не учтен вопрос первоначального добавления записи в базу, так что, для работоспособности необходимо в базе уже иметь запись с id=1.

Надеюсь этот код даст первоначальное понимание куда нужно двигаться.

```
<?php
    $dbHost = "localhost"; // Адрес БД
    $dbUser = "root"; // Ваш логин
    $dbPassword = ""; // Пароль
    $dbName = "note" // Название вашей базы

    // подключение и выбор базы данных
    $link = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPassword) or die('Не удалось соединиться: ' . mysql_error());  
    mysql_select_db($dbName) or die('Не удалось выбрать базу данных');


    // Ваша логика приложения
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])){
        if(isset($_POST['note'])){
            $text = $_POST['note'];
            // Выполняем SQL-запрос
            $query = "UPDATE `tablename` SET `text`='$text' WHERE id=1" ; // id=1 это для примера, вам исходя из потребностей нужно указать свое условие
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Запрос не удался: ' . mysql_error()); 
            echo '{"saved":1}';
        }
        exit;
        echo '{"saved":0}';
    }
    $note_content = '';
    // Выполняем SQL-запрос
    $query = "SELECT `text` FROM `tablename` WHERE id=1" ; // id=1 это для примера, вам исходя из потребностей нужно указать свое условие
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Запрос не удался: ' . mysql_error()); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    $note_content = $row['text'];
?>
```